# Downside of merging "worker desktop" and "worker Wi-Fi" VLANs?

Tags: vlan

In most of my clients' networks, the dominant method of connection for the workers is Wi-Fi (>90%), with few wired ethernet connections.

Given that, is there any benefit in keeping them on separate VLANs?  Voice, guest Wi-Fi, private servers, public-facing servers, management of course separate.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main benefits would be isolation - if there was a broadcast storm on your wired network, it would be isolated to just the Wired VLAN.

If this was shared with your Wireless network, it could have a fairly serious impact on all WLANs, not just the "Worker Wifi".

Some clients I've worked with also specify different access rights to wired (which means you're physically in the building) versus wireless (where this isn't a guarantee).

Comment: I can see that, certainly.  But given that few are in the wired region I expect most of the worker-device generated trouble will be in wifi to begin with.  My goal is "ensure quality equally without preferring wired users", my reasoning is "if it's not differentiated, it will be the same".  Physical presence is a good point, negated in most of my clients by various logmein/teamviewer/rdp laxity.

Comment: It's a lot harder to loop a Wifi network ;)

Comment: Now that's a fine point indeed.